# Make calculation on one column in CSV file and add it into the file using python

Tags: python, csv

I'm looking for a way in which I could make calculation of one column and add it into the column below.

Example: I have this file as input:

```
Name;Size
Paul;175
Simon;178
Jhon;120
```

Result expected in the other csv file:

```
  Total size = 473
  Average = 157
  Number of player called paul =1
```

This is what I have:

```
import operator

data = csv.reader(open('player.csv'),delimiter=';')
total=0 
for row in data:
    total += int(row[2])

with open("result.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(total)
```

But it seems that total cannot be written into the other csv file.
The thing is I don't know how to print all the calculation into the csv.

Any help would be great, 
BR

Comment: Try reading about the `csv` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). It's pretty insightful.

Comment: I did, i just thought my code was not usefull

Comment: There are two problems: first, you need to skip the first input line (the header). Second, the expression `row[2]` means the third column. The first column is `size[0]` and the second column is `row[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the two problems I mentioned in the comment, the output file is not really a CSV. It is just a plain text file, so you don't need to use `csv` for that.

```
import csv
import collections

data = csv.reader(open('player.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')
next(data)  # Skip the header

sizes = []
players_count = collections.Counter()
for name, size in data:
    players_count.update([name])
    sizes.append(float(size))

total = sum(sizes)
average = total / len(sizes)

with open('result.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('Total size = {}\n'.format(total))
    f.write('Average = {}\n'.format(average))

    # Output count of players, sorted by count in decending order
    f.write('\nCount Player\n')
    for player, count in players_count.most_common():
        f.write('{:5} {}\n'.format(count, player))
```

Comment: I updated the code to use the `collections.Counter` to do the counting of players' names.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the `zip*` function to separate the name and the size column into independent iterables. The central computation is of course similar to the solution presented by @Hai Vu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
from collections import Counter

header, *data = csv.reader(open('player.csv', 'r'), delimiter=';')

# separate names and sizes into individual iterables
names, sizes = zip(*data)
sizes = list(map(int, sizes))

total_size = sum(sizes)
mean_size = total_size // len(sizes)

# pass all names to the counter at once
name_counts = Counter(names)

with open("result.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    print("Total size = {}".format(total_size), file=outfile)
    print("Average size = {}".format(mean_size), file=outfile)

    name_occurences = ["Number of players called {} = {}".format(name, count) for name, count in name_counts.most_common()]
    print("\n".join(name_occurences), file=outfile)
```

I used integer division here to make sure the fraction is dropped as in your expected output. If you would like floats just remove one of the slashes and change the average size output to

```
    print("Average size = {:2f}".format(mean_size), file=outfile)
```

to round the average size to two decimal positions.